# Why does php keep throwing "Use of undefined constant" error for a named class?

Tags: php

I'm confused why this doesn't work...

```
class Request {
    public static function uri(){
        return 'test';
    }
}

var_dump(Request);
```

I know it's probably something super obvious. I'm new to PHP, and this is driving me crazy.

Why am I getting `Use of undefined constant` error? My goal is to be able to call my `uri()` function.

Comment: You never instantiate a class. You just var_dump the word "Request" with no quotes hence the error you receive

Comment: To get you started on the basics: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function nor the class. Adding the backslash (`\`) is good practice on calling the class. And to call a static function you need to call with `::`.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

class Request {
    public static function uri(){
        return 'test';
    }
}

var_dump(\Request::uri());
```

Output:

```
➜  Desktop php demo.php
string(4) "test"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var_dump(new Request());
```

You aren't passing in an instance of the class, just a name that looks like a constant, which is why you are getting the error

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Was editing an explanation in as you wrote that. Relax

Comment: But why does Request::uri(); also not work. Isn't the point of static functions to work even without an instance?

Comment: @MagdiGamal where are you calling the function? From the code you have provided you are not calling the function.